# Clicking trough a visibility:hidden element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a div with 2 elements inside: an image and an another div (about). The image is hiding the about div.
Is that possible to make elements which are in the about div clickable when the image disappear with a hover property ?
Thanks in advance !

Also, here's my code but the elements aren't clickable

```css
#logo {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  margin-top: 12.5px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
  transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
}

.blue_border:hover #logo {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.blue_border {
  width: 625px;
  height: 625px;
  background-image: url("./border.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
}

#about {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -605px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #25B8EE;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue_border">
  <img id="logo" src="./logo.png" />
  <!-- Img is "on" the about div" -->
  <div id="about">
    <a href="#">I want to be clicked :-(</a>
  </div>
  <div class="la-ball-scale-multiple">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `pointer-events:none` ?

Comment: It's disabling the hover detection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With my current code, I think the *z-index: -1;* in #about **is** the problem: #blue_border is an image background and it's upper my "about" div... So I'm trying to find a way to replace that background.
Edit:

Okay. I figured out that the element with *z-index: -1;* will never be clickable the way I want to.
So I decided to reverse everything: the logo has now the property *z-index: -1;* and the about div (which is upper now) is hidden until the hover trigger. I also changed my background image by a border.
My code now :

```css
/*Under #about and visible*/ 
#logo {
  z-index: -1;
}
.blue_border {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 15px solid #71d1f4;
  border-radius: 100%;
  /*background-image: url("./border.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
  background-position: 50%;
}
/*Hidden first*/
#about {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -605px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #25B8EE;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
  transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
}
/*Unhidden on hover*/
.blue_border:hover #about
{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

***I didn't changed my html***

Thanks anyway guys. It was my very first question and I'm glad that some of you already answered me !

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I understand it completely, but you cannot click under another element but you can use CSS display: none attr or you do this in a fake way. You can listen to the top element for this and check other conditions on javascript.

Comment: Yeah but when I make a hover with display:none, my div is acting weird (This [imgur.com/Yg55N4H] instead of this [imgur.com/NKhaZTm]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you may can use the `pointer-events: none` on the overlay to cause it to not receive click events, and allow them to pass through.

```js
function whoWasClicked(e) {
  console.log(`${e.target.id} was clicked!`);
};

document.querySelector('#lowerElement').addEventListener('click', whoWasClicked);
document.querySelector('#upperElement').addEventListener('click', whoWasClicked);
```

```css
#lowerElement {
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  min-width: 25vw;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 37vh;
  left: 37vw;
  
  z-index: 1;
}

#upperElement {
  min-width: 25vw;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 37vh;
  left: 37vw;
  
  z-index: 2;
  
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="lowerElement">Click Me</div>

<div id="upperElement">Overlay</div>
```

Comment: My problem is that my "lowerElement" is in the "upperElement" and this method disable the :hover trigger.